# KendoUI re-posts when delete is used

Tags: kendo-ui

When new entry added into datagrid, and if page is not refreshed but some rows deleted,
tornado receives same added data as post, along with delete method

Why is that happening? I have differnt transport methods for each:

```
    transport: {
  read: {
    url: '/api/notes/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'GET',
  },
  create: {
    url: '/api/notes/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST'
  },
  update: {
    url: '/api/notes/',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'PUT',
  },
  destroy: {
    url: function(row) {
      return '/api/notes/' + row.id;
    },
    type: 'DELETE',
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, doing $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read(); on create.complete fixed it.